# Using a C++ dll file method in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a dll created in c++ which exports function using the .def file.The function is written as follows:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MethodA(int par1,int par2,char *par3)
{....}
```

and then the method is declared in the .def file as

```
MethodA       @1
```

Now my question is how can I use this method in my C# application ?
I tried adding the dll file as a reference in my C# application and I get the following message

```
"A reference to the filename.dll could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible and that the file is a valid assembly or COM component."
```

**Edit:**
After readings the comments posted here. I am attempting to use the file in the following manner

```
 [DllImport("C:\\Filename.dll")]
        public static extern int MethodA(int par1,int par2,String par3);
```

and the I am using it as such

```
 MethodA(1,2,"SomeString);
```

This is the error I am getting

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you did fine AFAIK on the C++ side, you need to do more on the C# side, You need to create a C# method declaration as something like this:

```
[DllImport ("your_dll_name")]
extern int MethodA (int par1, int par2);
```

Decorate with `static`, `unsafe` etc. as desired and needed.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Just edited my post with the error I am getting

Comment: `"your_dll_name"` stands for the base name of the DLL, not its file name, so in your case `[DllImport("Filename")]` with `Filename.dll` somewhere the program can find it ... drop it where the .exe is for a starter.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to pass strings, read up on `LPStr` and string marshalling - this is not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for C# to interact with a C++ dll is to use COM Interop.  You want to create a COM component in C++ that encapsulates the functionality of your C++ dll.  You can then reference the COM component from your C# project.

Comment: I donot have the option of changing the dll

Comment: You don't need to change the .dll; you create a new C++ dll that is also a COM object and calls the methods in the .dll you want to call.